# How to use Webpack 3 in debug mode

Tags: debugging, webpack, browserify

I want to use `webpack 3` in debug mode. My webpack.config file is:

```
module.exports = {
    progress: true,
    watch: true,
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // JSON
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json-loader" },
            // React & ES2015
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                //exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                },
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            debug: true
        })
    ]
}
```

The bundle works perfect, but when I press `CTRL+P` in browser (with debug window open an `Source` tab selected) it appears only `Index.bundle.js`. In the past I used `braoserify` to create `bundles` and using the following config I could see all `bundle` files in the console source tab:

```
browserify({
    entries: ['js/index.js'],
    transform: [babelify] ,//reactify],
    debug: true
})
.bundle()
.on('error', function onError() {
    gutil.log(gutil.colors.bgRed('  ! Browserify error: '), arguments);
})
.on('end', function onEnd() {
    gutil.log('  > Browserify finished bundling');
})
//.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(source('index-boundle.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
```

Is there any way to see all `budle` files in brawser's console using `webpac 3`?